# I can not upload my text file into R

Tags: r, csv, text

I saved a txt file titled "windmillData" on my desktop. This is a snipit of how the data is formatted in the txt document
The data analyses Wind speed at a candidate site "Cspd"(y variable) and compares wind speed at a reference site "Rspd" (x variable)

```
Date Cspd Rspd
"2002/1/1/0" 6.9 5.9666
"2002/1/1/6" 7.1 7.2176
"2002/1/1/12" 7.8 7.9405
"2002/1/1/18" 6.9 6.0174
"2002/1/2/0" 5.5 6.1646
"2002/1/2/6" 3.1 1.7687
"2002/1/2/12" 6.8 4.6471
"2002/1/2/18" 11.4 10.8734
"2002/1/3/0" 12.9 11.7198
"2002/1/3/6" 13.5 13.0118
"2002/1/3/12" 9.6 6.3998
"2002/1/3/18" 8.0 8.2706
"2002/1/4/0" 8.3 8.3522
"2002/1/4/6" 8.8 7.9027
"2002/1/4/12" 6.1 6.7136
"2002/1/4/18" 8.4 9.6341
"2002/1/5/0" 8.5 8.7918
"2002/1/5/6" 9.6 10.2506
"2002/1/5/12" 10.4 10.8894
"2002/1/5/18" 10.0 7.6393
"2002/1/6/0" 10.6 8.2217
"2002/1/6/6" 8.9 7.4820
"2002/1/6/12" 9.4 9.2628
"2002/1/6/18" 8.8 4.8476
"2002/1/7/0" 6.1 4.4194
"2002/1/7/6" 13.5 11.3922
"2002/1/7/12" 11.5 10.6574
"2002/1/7/18" 9.9 9.2053
"2002/1/8/0" 10.5 11.2537
"2002/1/8/6" 11.7 13.2537
"2002/1/8/12" 11.2 8.6108
```

I have been trying to get the data loaded into R but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
    > read.table(file = "windmillData.txt", sep=",")
    Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In file(file, "rt") :
      cannot open file 'windmillData.txt': No such file or directory

> read.table(file = "windmillData.txt", sep="/t",header=TRUE)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'windmillData.txt': No such file or directory
```

Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should place your data into your working directory

Comment: try `getwd()` and see what is returned. if not your desktop, run `setwd("pathToDesktopHere")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as RStudent replied, you should make sure where your directory is (probably Documents). But, you don't need to place the file in your working directory or change your directory. You can load your file as something like:

read.table('C:\Users\user\Documents\windmillData.txt', sep="/t")

Answer (score 0):

It has been loaded in code below:

```
> ddf = read.table(text='
+ Date Cspd Rspd
+ "2002/1/1/0" 6.9 5.9666
+ "2002/1/1/6" 7.1 7.2176
+ "2002/1/1/12" 7.8 7.9405
+ "2002/1/1/18" 6.9 6.0174
+ "2002/1/2/0" 5.5 6.1646
+ "2002/1/2/6" 3.1 1.7687
+ "2002/1/2/12" 6.8 4.6471
+ "2002/1/2/18" 11.4 10.8734
+ "2002/1/3/0" 12.9 11.7198
+ "2002/1/3/6" 13.5 13.0118
+ "2002/1/3/12" 9.6 6.3998
+ "2002/1/3/18" 8.0 8.2706
+ "2002/1/4/0" 8.3 8.3522
+ "2002/1/4/6" 8.8 7.9027
+ "2002/1/4/12" 6.1 6.7136
+ "2002/1/4/18" 8.4 9.6341
+ "2002/1/5/0" 8.5 8.7918
+ "2002/1/5/6" 9.6 10.2506
+ "2002/1/5/12" 10.4 10.8894
+ "2002/1/5/18" 10.0 7.6393
+ "2002/1/6/0" 10.6 8.2217
+ "2002/1/6/6" 8.9 7.4820
+ "2002/1/6/12" 9.4 9.2628
+ "2002/1/6/18" 8.8 4.8476
+ "2002/1/7/0" 6.1 4.4194
+ "2002/1/7/6" 13.5 11.3922
+ "2002/1/7/12" 11.5 10.6574
+ "2002/1/7/18" 9.9 9.2053
+ "2002/1/8/0" 10.5 11.2537
+ "2002/1/8/6" 11.7 13.2537
+ "2002/1/8/12" 11.2 8.6108
+ ', header=T)
> 
> ddf
          Date Cspd    Rspd
1   2002/1/1/0  6.9  5.9666
2   2002/1/1/6  7.1  7.2176
3  2002/1/1/12  7.8  7.9405
4  2002/1/1/18  6.9  6.0174
5   2002/1/2/0  5.5  6.1646
6   2002/1/2/6  3.1  1.7687
7  2002/1/2/12  6.8  4.6471
8  2002/1/2/18 11.4 10.8734
9   2002/1/3/0 12.9 11.7198
10  2002/1/3/6 13.5 13.0118
11 2002/1/3/12  9.6  6.3998
12 2002/1/3/18  8.0  8.2706
13  2002/1/4/0  8.3  8.3522
14  2002/1/4/6  8.8  7.9027
15 2002/1/4/12  6.1  6.7136
16 2002/1/4/18  8.4  9.6341
17  2002/1/5/0  8.5  8.7918
18  2002/1/5/6  9.6 10.2506
19 2002/1/5/12 10.4 10.8894
20 2002/1/5/18 10.0  7.6393
21  2002/1/6/0 10.6  8.2217
22  2002/1/6/6  8.9  7.4820
23 2002/1/6/12  9.4  9.2628
24 2002/1/6/18  8.8  4.8476
25  2002/1/7/0  6.1  4.4194
26  2002/1/7/6 13.5 11.3922
27 2002/1/7/12 11.5 10.6574
28 2002/1/7/18  9.9  9.2053
29  2002/1/8/0 10.5 11.2537
30  2002/1/8/6 11.7 13.2537
31 2002/1/8/12 11.2  8.6108
> 
> dput(ddf)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 
7L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 
21L, 24L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 28L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 30L), .Label = c("2002/1/1/0", 
"2002/1/1/12", "2002/1/1/18", "2002/1/1/6", "2002/1/2/0", "2002/1/2/12", 
"2002/1/2/18", "2002/1/2/6", "2002/1/3/0", "2002/1/3/12", "2002/1/3/18", 
"2002/1/3/6", "2002/1/4/0", "2002/1/4/12", "2002/1/4/18", "2002/1/4/6", 
"2002/1/5/0", "2002/1/5/12", "2002/1/5/18", "2002/1/5/6", "2002/1/6/0", 
"2002/1/6/12", "2002/1/6/18", "2002/1/6/6", "2002/1/7/0", "2002/1/7/12", 
"2002/1/7/18", "2002/1/7/6", "2002/1/8/0", "2002/1/8/12", "2002/1/8/6"
), class = "factor"), Cspd = c(6.9, 7.1, 7.8, 6.9, 5.5, 3.1, 
6.8, 11.4, 12.9, 13.5, 9.6, 8, 8.3, 8.8, 6.1, 8.4, 8.5, 9.6, 
10.4, 10, 10.6, 8.9, 9.4, 8.8, 6.1, 13.5, 11.5, 9.9, 10.5, 11.7, 
11.2), Rspd = c(5.9666, 7.2176, 7.9405, 6.0174, 6.1646, 1.7687, 
4.6471, 10.8734, 11.7198, 13.0118, 6.3998, 8.2706, 8.3522, 7.9027, 
6.7136, 9.6341, 8.7918, 10.2506, 10.8894, 7.6393, 8.2217, 7.482, 
9.2628, 4.8476, 4.4194, 11.3922, 10.6574, 9.2053, 11.2537, 13.2537, 
8.6108)), .Names = c("Date", "Cspd", "Rspd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
>
```